# How to color a region i.e the intersection of two object?

Tags: svg

I want to color an intersection of two object, let's say a circle and a rectangle.

What I have tried so far is to defined a path bounding that region then add the `fill` attribute, but it seems too complicated.

Is there any other ways to do so?

Let me elabotare more one the problem:

```html
<svg width="352" height="57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <line y2="0.75" x2="103.95" y1="43.15" x1="42.35" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <line y2="50.35" x2="201.55" y1="0.75" x1="103.95" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <line y2="19.15" x2="239.95" y1="49.55" x1="201.55" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <line y2="55.95" x2="282.35" y1="18.35" x1="240.75" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <line y2="37.55" x2="351.15" y1="31.95" x1="0.75" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

I have a set of lines which the end of one is another end of the other.
I have another line intersecing these line.
How could I color the region i.e the triangles formed by these line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with `opacity` to let the color of an overlapped element shine through like shown here:

```html
<svg  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g style="stroke:#000; stroke-width:1">
<circle cx="50"  cy="50" r="50" opacity="0.5"  style="fill:red" />
<circle cx="100" cy="50" r="50" opacity="0.5" style="fill:yellow" />
<rect x="0" y="70" width="150" height="50" fill-opacity="0.5" style="fill:blue" />
</g>
</svg>
```

You can also specify the opacity levels separately for `stroke` and `fill` by using `stroke-opacity` and `fill-opacity`.

**Edit:**

Looking at your edited question again: when you are dealing with a succession of lines (and curves) you should use `<path>` elements instead of individual `<line>` elements. One of its advantages is that it comes with a fill behaviour that is *almost* exactly as you want it to be. However, to suit the requirements of your example you would need to find the positions where the straight line enters and leaves the zig-zag shape. These positions then define the points used for your filled path. The "original" (non-filled) path is then plotted over the filled path:

```html
<svg width="352" height="57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M56,33       103.95,0.75 201.55,50.35 239.95,19.15 260,36z
         M0.75,31.95 351.15,37.55" style="fill:yellow" />
<path d="M42.35,43.15 103.95,0.75 201.55,50.35 239.95,19.15 282.35,55.95 
         M0.75,31.95 351.15,37.55" style="stroke:black;fill:none"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<clipPath>` to clip the rect with the circle like so:

```css
svg{width:100vh;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="50 50 200 100">
<clipPath id="clip">
<use xlink:href="#c"  />
</clipPath>
<g fill="none" stroke="black" >
<circle id="c" cx="100" cy="100" r="30" />
<rect id="r" x="90" y="80" width="80" height="60" /> 
</g>
<use xlink:href="#r" clip-path="url(#clip)" fill="gold" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I got it. But in the case of the region between let say a circle and a secant line, how one of the two regions can be colored?

Comment: A easy way to do it would be drawing a polygon with one side being the line and do the same as above.